# Line in vector form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Given the line y=3x my book states it is $\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 3\\\end{array}\right)$ as a matrix. Why is it not $\left(\begin{array}{c}3 \\ 1\\\end{array}\right)$, I thought the upper number was x and the lower number y?

Comment: Depends on the book and the notation. Need more information.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=1$, then $y=3\cdot 1=3$.

Answer (score 0):

$\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 3\\\end{array}\right)$ is the basis vector, the whole vector space (line) is the span of it.